# How to call validate method manually in an LWC flow component

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

I have an LWC component which has a lighting datatable component. I need to validate unsaved changes in this table, so I use the `validate` callback to check if there are any unsaved changes, and return an error if there are. Therefore stopping the user from going to the next screen if they have unsaved changes.

My validate method (simplified) looks like this:

```
@api
validate() {
    
    // unsaved changes
    if (this.draftValues.length) {
        return {
            isValid: false,
            errorMessage: 'Please save your changes before clicking next.'
        };
    }
    return { isValid: true };
}
```

And here is my function that gets called when you click cancel:

```
handleCancel(event) {
    const attributeChangeEvent = new FlowAttributeChangeEvent(
        'draftValues',
        this.draftValues
    );
    this.dispatchEvent(attributeChangeEvent); 
}
```

I've tried using `FlowAttributeChangeEvent` but the `validate` callback is never executed here.

How can I have the `validate` method triggered correctly (obviously I can't just do `this.validate()`) when the user clicks cancel, in order to remove the error message I added in the first place.

Comment: Hi, @ViqMontana, were you able to do this?

Comment: @SergioAndresPedrazaJerez I think my solution in the end was to set `this.errors.rows = {};` in the cancel function. I wasn't able to call the 'validate` function manually.